# Find a metric $D$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ so $(X,D)$ is complete and topologically equivalent to $(X,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to find a metric $D$ on the set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the origin, so that it forms a complete metric space. There is also the restriction that this metric space has the same open sets of $(X,d)$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In other words, I wish to find a metric $D$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ so $(X,D)$ is complete and topologically equivalent to $(X,d)$

My attempts so far have revolved around the function $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2},$$
so that the Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}^2$ converging to the origin under the Euclidean metric are no longer Cauchy in $X$ under whatever metric $D$ I eventually find.

I let $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, I tried naively defining $D(u,v)=|f(u)-f(v)|$, but it doesn't work because $D(u,-u)=0$. Then, I tried $D=\frac{1}{(d(u,v))^2}$, but it's not defined when $u=v$.

I'm not sure what direction to take. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: turn the punctured plane into a cylinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D(x,y)=\|x-y\|+|\frac 1 {\|x\|} -\frac 1 {\|y\|}|$ is such a metric.

If $U$ is any open set in  complete metric space  $(X,d)$ then $D(x,y)=d(x,y)+|\frac  1{d(x,U^{c})}-\frac  1{d(y,U^{c})}|$ defines a new metric which has same open sets as $(X,d)$ and $(U,D)$ is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm having some trouble understanding. The problem gives $d$ already as the standard distance formula in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Are you using a different set of notation or are you defining some new $d$ which we use to find $D$?

Comment: I have defined  a new metric. (I have changed the notation now).

Answer (score 1):

To help you make @yoyo's suggestion in the comments more concrete, consider the map $ F $ which sends $ (x,y) \in X $ to the point $ (r, \theta) \in \tilde{X} = (0,\infty) \times[0,2\pi) $ given by the cylindrical coordinates.  We can now take the distance between two points $ \mathbf{x}_1 = (x_1, y_1), \mathbf{x}_2 = (x_2, y_2) $ to be the distance
$$ D(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2) :=  \tilde{D}(F(\mathbf{x}_1), F(\mathbf{x}_2)) 
$$ between their images on the cylinder.  I will leave it to you to devise the explicit formulas, if those are necessary for your problem.

Let me know if you want a hint for proving topological equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure how to make sense of your distance function. What is meant by $\tilde{D}(F(\mathbf{x}_1), F(\mathbf{x}_2))$? Converting to cylindrical coordinates, I believe $F(\mathbf{x}) = 1/r^2$. 

I think I'm not visualizing the cylinder the way you are. If I stretch the pole out to some finite radius $R$, would the distance on the cylinder be $((r_1-r_2)^2+(R\theta_1-R\theta_2)^2)^{1/2}$ ? How do I deal with the "seam" at $\theta = 0$?

Comment: The cylindrical map is the usual $ F(x,y) = ( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, atan(x,y)) $.  You are correct that we "glue" the line $ \theta = 2\pi $ to the line $ \theta = 0$. This doesn't present a problem.  In fact it makes the angle function $ \theta = atan(x,y) $ continuous.

Comment: The distance function $ \tilde{D} $ is along the lines you described.  Remove the meaningless $R$ from your formula, and find an angle distance formula that takes into account that $ 2\pi \equiv 0 $.