# Find a metric on $X = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0), (0,1)\}$ so $(X,D)$ is complete and topologically equivalent to $(X,d)$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I originally asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936552/find-a-metric-d-on-x-mathbbr2-0-0-so-x-d-is-complete-and-topol) with only one "pole" at the origin, however I wanted to understand the problem in the case of multiple "poles." The advice I got in the other post was to convert to cylindrical coordinates. While I'm currently trying to understand their advice, I don't think this would generalize readily to an $X$ with multiple holes.

> I'm trying to find a metric $D$ on the set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the origin, so that it forms a complete metric space. There is also the restriction that this metric space has the same open sets of $(X,d)$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> In other words, I wish to find a metric $D$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^2−\{(0,0)\}$ so $(X,D)$ is complete and topologically equivalent to $(X,d)$

> My attempts so far have revolved around the function
> $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2},$$
> so that the Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}^2$ converging to the origin under the Euclidean metric are no longer Cauchy in $X$ under whatever metric $D$ I eventually find.

> I let $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, I tried naively defining $D(u,v)=|f(u)−f(v)|$, but it doesn't work because $D(u,−u)=0$. Then, I tried $D=\frac{1}{(d(u,v))^2}$, but it's not defined when u=v.

> I'm not sure what direction to take. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So in this case, where $X = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0), (0,1)\}$ so $(X,D)$, I would look at the function
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+y^2},$$
at which point I'm stuck. I want to find an explicit formula, but all my attempts so far failed to even satisfy the conditions for being a *metric*, let alone making $(X,D)$ complete and whatnot. I would really appreciate any help in the right direction.

Comment: My answer for your previous question [ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936552/find-a-metric-d-on-x-mathbbr2-0-0-so-x-d-is-complete-and-topol ] covers this case. If you want more details in that answer I will be happy to  provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $p=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $q=\langle 0,1\rangle$, for $x\in X$ let

$$f(x)=\frac1{\min\{d(x,p),d(x,q)\}}\,,$$

and for $x,y\in X$ let

$$D(x,y)=d(x,y)+|f(x)-f(y)|\,.$$

Show that $D$ generates the same topology on $X$ as $d$ and that $\langle X,D\rangle$ is complete.

More generally, if $G$ is open in a complete metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$, let

$$f(x)=\frac1{d(x,X\setminus G)}$$

and

$$D(x,y)=d(x,y)+|f(x)-f(y)|\,;$$

then $D$ generates the same topology on $X$ as $d$, and $\langle X,D\rangle$ is complete.